# Не работает функция isdigit

Tags: python

```
from functools import reduce
def increment_string(strng):
    forsel = []
    for i in strng:
        if i.isdigit() :
            forsel.append(i)
        else :
            pass
        rust = [ n.lstrip('0') for n in forsel ]
        return rust
    return None
```

Программа должна выводить из строки - "foo002" - цифру 2 . Без букв и ведущих нулей .
Но isdigit() просто не проверяет его на наличие цифры изза чего в список ничего не попадает .

Прошу не бить палками я просто новичок который залез в интернет в поисках задачек . Заранее спасибо

Comment: функция isdigit() работает! Не работает код, в котором ты эту функцию используешь. Да и на самом деле код тоже работает, просто не так, как ты придумал, а так, как ты написал.

Answer (score 0):

ну так вы из цикла выходите на первом же символе

```
for i in strng:
    if i.isdigit() :
        forsel.append(i)
    else :
        pass
    rust = [ n.lstrip('0') for n in forsel ]
    return rust # вот тут сразу выход из функции
return None
```

по идее ваш код должен был бы выглядеть так:

```
def increment_string(strng):
    forsel = []
    for i in strng:
        if i.isdigit() :
            forsel.append(i)
    rust = [ n.lstrip('0') for n in forsel ]
    return ''.join(rust)
```

и если вы умеете в цикле собирать массивы то почему было не сделать так:

```
forsel = [i for i in strng if i.isdigit()]
```